# Argument not specified for parameter 'item' of 'Public Function Add(item As Object) As Integer?

Tags: vb.net

So i am making a virtual os and im making a new user function.In the Login form i used a combobox for Selecting users and i'm stuck at creating a method to add the input for the new user to the combobox collection. this is what i have right now

```
Public Class NewUser

Private Sub FlatButton2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles FlatButton2.Click
    Form1.UserName(1) = FlatTextBox1.Text
    Form1.FlatComboBox1.Items.Add = FlatTextBox1.Text
End Sub
End Class
```

i know its not much yet. but when i excecute this code it gives an error:Argument not specified for parameter 'item' of 'Public Function Add(item As Object) As Integer.
i really dont get how to fix this error.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: read the error message carefully. it is telling you that you are not using it correctly: `Add(item As Object)` is not the same as `.Add = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` isn't a property, it's a method on `ComboBox.ObjectCollection` with one parameter, an `Object`. You need to invoke it like so

```
Form1.FlatComboBox1.Items.Add(FlatTextBox1.Text)
```

See [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) for more info.